# Automating a daily displacement of files bearing dates in their names

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I'm trying to get a script to move all files created today to a folder named with today's date.

I have some IP cameras sending images to a folder.

The names of the images are :

```
2018-09-11_12-44-19_Inside.jpg
2018-09-11_12-26-28_Outside1.jpg
2018-09-11_12-21-48_Inside.jpg
2018-09-11_12-15-58_Outside2.jpg 
…
```

I want to put a cron job to run a script daily at 23hr59minutes to move all of today's files to a folder dated today.

I am stuck with my script and seeking some help.

```
today=$(date -I)
todayFolder=$(mkdir /share/CameraCaptures/Trial/$today)
actualFolder=/share/CameraCaptures/Trial/$today
chmod 777 $actualFolder
datedTodayfiles=$actualFolder/$today"_*"
order=$(mv $datedTodayfiles $actualFolder)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
mv: unable to rename `/share/CameraCaptures/Trial/2018-09-11/2018-09-11_*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You've (understandably, as it is quite strange) slightly misunderstood bash's quoting syntax. In general, you need to put double-quotes around "$variables" (so that spaces don't break scripts) -- but if you put quotes around wildcards*, it will just take them literally. They have to be unquoted to work. That's why `mv` is being asked to move a file which actually has `*` in its name. (Normally when you use `*`, bash replaces it with a list of files, before passing it to `mv`.)

Unfortunately trying to collect a list of files into a variable has even more quirks, so I'd recommend this time just not using one for `$datedTodayfiles`.

It would be easiest to just go `order=$(mv "$actualFolder/$today"_* $todayFolder)`.

Also:

- watch out because `$todayFolder` probably isn't being set to anything and `$actualFolder` seems to be the wrong thing.
- you probably don't really want to `chmod 777`

Comment: thank you
yes, thank for the note abt todayfolder and actualfolder being set to nothing.

Comment: ammended as per you help but still issues:

mv: unable to stat `/share/CameraCaptures/Trial//2018-09-11_12-48-49_Inside.jpg/2018-09-11_12-06-51_Inside.jpg': Not a directory

Comment: today=$(date -I)

todayFolder=$(mkdir /share/CameraCaptures/Trial/$today)

actualFolder=/share/CameraCaptures/Trial/

#chmod 777 $todayFolder

datedTodayfiles=$actualFolder/$today"_*"

sleep 2

mv "$actualFolder$today"_* $todayFolder

Answer (score 0):

```
today=$(date -I)
todayFolder=$(mkdir /share/CameraCaptures/Trial/$today)
actualFolder=/share/CameraCaptures/Trial/
chmod 777 $actualFolder$today
sleep 1
mv "$actualFolder$today"_* "$actualFolder$today"/
```